# how to convert xml data to Json. PS: I have a CDATA content as well

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I have used XML to JSON conversion in xslt. I used following xslt to convert my xml to json. Problem is my CDATA content is lost.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Error>
<ECId>fc14e3645c3065f2</ECId>
<ErrorNumber>SYS003</ErrorNumber>
<ErrorDescription>Technical Error</ErrorDescription>
<Timestamp>2015-03-03T17:50:18.185+10:00</Timestamp>
<UserId>1212</UserId>
<ServiceName>POP</ServiceName>
<OperationName>XA_Call</OperationName>
<InitialPayload>
<![CDATA[
<CustomerInformation> <NS1:ProductSystemID>GCIS</NS1:ProductSystemID> <NS1:ProductSystemCustomerID>00000</NS1:ProductSystemCustomerID> <NS1:IntegrationID>00</NS1:IntegrationID> <NS1:BrandName>000</NS1:BrandName> <NS1:LastUpdatedDateTime>2014-11-06-13.50.31.374000</NS1:LastUpdatedDateTime> <NS1:ChangedByUserID>POP</NS1:ChangedByUserID> <NS1:ModificationNo>258</NS1:ModificationNo> <NS1:SourceSystemID>OWF</NS1:SourceSystemID> <NS1:Individual> <NS1:Contact> <CustomerInformation>
]]>
</InitialPayload>
<CausingError>
<SourceErrorDescription>subLanguageExecutionFault</SourceErrorDescription>
</CausingError>
</Error>
```

My problem is that CDATA content from initial payload is removed.

Result is `{"Error" : "ECId" : "fc14e3645c3065f2", "ErrorNumber" : "SYS003", "ErrorDescription" : " ", "Timestamp" : "2015-03-03T17:50:18.185+10:00", "UserId" : "1212", "ServiceName" : "POP", "OperationName" : "XA_Call", "**InitialPayload" : " "**, "CausingError" : "SourceErrorDescription" : ""}`

My XSLT is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
<xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="detect" />
<xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
<xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="obj-content" />
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) &gt; 0">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attr" />
<xsl:if test="count(@*) &gt; 0 and (count(child::*) &gt; 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
<xsl:apply-templates select="./*" mode="detect" />
<xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*) and (name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) or name(following-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()))">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*) and name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) != name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
<xsl:text>{"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
<xsl:text>{"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
<xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, ' '))"><xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '
 '), ' ')"/>
<xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
<xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '
 ')"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PS:  I think I need to change something here below:

```
 <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
                <xsl:text>"text" : "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
```

Help appreciated.

Expected output :

```
{"Error" : "ECId" : "fc14e3645c3065f2", "ErrorNumber" : "SYS003", "ErrorDescription" : " ", "Timestamp" : "2015-03-03T17:50:18.185+10:00", "UserId" : "1212", "ServiceName" : "POP", "OperationName" : "XA_Call", "InitialPayload" : "<MY XML DATA>", "CausingError" : "SourceErrorDescription" : ""}
```

Thanks,
MS

Comment: **1.** Please post the expected output of the transformation. **2.** IMHO, it would be better to write a **custom** XSLT stylesheet that fits your expected input, instead of trying to adapt some generic (and rather opaque) code. **3.** Keep in mind that CDATA is not XML and cannot be parsed as XML; you must treat it as text and, if necessary, parse it as text.

Comment: Thanks Michael,   I want output like {"Error" : "ECId" : "fc14e3645c3065f2", "ErrorNumber" : "SYS003", "ErrorDescription" : " ", "Timestamp" : "2015-03-03T17:50:18.185+10:00", "UserId" : "1212", "ServiceName" : "POP", "OperationName" : "XA_Call", "InitialPayload" : "<MY XML DATA>", "CausingError" : "SourceErrorDescription" : ""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Resolved the issue. Parsing of CDATA is not at all required. I skipped the part and slightly tweaked my XSLT.

It works fine.

Thanks Again.

Cheers
MS